# How to prove that the expected value minimizes mean square error

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, mse

[In this wiki subpage about conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#L2_random_variables) we read that if $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{P})$ is a probability space and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable with mean and variance, then

$$\min\limits_{c\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}((X - c)^{2}) = \mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}(X))^2).$$
I.e., the expected value $c=\mathbb{E}(X)$ minimizes $\mathbb{E}((X - c)^{2}).$

My question is how to prove it?